# quickest way to append foreign keys from one dataframe to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This frustrates me because I'm sure it's something easy to do but I just can't for the life of me come up with an optimal solution.

Basically let's say I have `df1`, which has columns `vehicle`, `checkpoint`, which represent at which time each vehicle in a race passed each checkpoint during the lap. But certain checkpoints for the same race were not recorded.

Then I have `df2` which contains a single column `checkpoint` which contains checkpoint data that should have been included in `df1`.

I'm trying to find a fast way to essentially add these checkpoints to each unique `lap` value in `df1`.

For example:
`df1 = pd.DataFrame({'vehicle': [1,1,2,2,3,3], 'checkpoint': [1,5,1,5,1,5]}) df2 = pd.DataFrame({"checkpoints": range(2,5)})`

What I want is to quickly generate a dataframe that adds all the df2 missing checkpoints to each vehicle in df1, so that the resulting dataframe has checkpoints 1 through 5 for each of the 3 unique vehicles.

Expected output would be something like the following, but checkpoints and vehicles dont necessarily have to be in order. The important thing is that all 5 checkpoints are accounted for in all 3 vehicles:

```
vehicle checkpoints
0   1   1
1   1   2
2   1   3
3   1   4
4   1   5
5   2   1
6   2   2
7   2   3
8   2   4
9   2   5
10  3   1
11  3   2
12  3   3
13  3   4
14  3   5

I've come up with solutions using list comprehensions and concatenation but it's far too slow on larger datasets. I'm not the most at ease with using apply either, so if there's a way to use apply or an entirely different and faster solution, I would be very much appreciative.

If you need more information don't hesitate to ask.
```

Comment: Check out MERGE operations on Python Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: Do they have the same order? Please provide your expected output, too.

Comment: @Fourier sorry, just updated. I really suck at formatting on stack overflow :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'vehicle': [1,1,2,2,3,3], 'checkpoint': [1,5,1,5,1,5]}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"checkpoint": range(2,5)})
```

**`merge`**-based solution

Concatenate `df1` and full outer merge of unique vehicles from `df1` and missing checkpoints from `df2`:

```py
pd.concat([df1,
           pd.merge(df1[['vehicle']].drop_duplicates().assign(temp=1),
                    df2.assign(temp=1), how='outer').drop('temp', axis=1)]
         ).sort_values(['vehicle', 'checkpoint']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output as shown by OP.

---

**`reindex`**-based solution

```
import itertools

all_vehicles = df1.vehicle.unique().tolist()
all_checkpoints = (df1.checkpoint.unique().tolist()
                   + df2.checkpoint.unique().tolist())

(df1.set_index(['vehicle', 'checkpoint'])
    .reindex(index=itertools.product(all_vehicles, all_checkpoints))
    .reset_index())
```

Comment: Thanks! Dunno if it's the fastest but it's definitely faster than my solution where I would concat for each unique course id. Need to work more with merges to better understand how to fully utilise them, especially when assigning a temporary column which was helpful in this application

Comment: could also outer merge on an appropriate index, then the temporary column is not required. but it remains a bit awkward in pandas...